# Outputting [Obj Obj], [Obj Obj] after pushing to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to create key value pairs and push to an array but all I get is [Obj Obj], [Obj Obj].  I've created a function that passes a name and val which are used to assign the key and value to a JavaScript object.  Here's my code.  Not sure what I'm missing:

```
var currentpos = 1;
var positions = [];

function pushToAry(name, val){
    var obj = {};
    obj[name] = val;
    positions.push(obj);
}

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    $('.things').append("<div class='shell'></div>");
    var thispos = $('.shell:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').position().left;
    var currentnum = "currentnum";
    currentnum = currentnum + i;
    pushToAry(currentnum, thispos);
    currentpos++;
    alert(positions);
}
```

Comment: [Object object] is usually just the string representation of objects, as alert needs a string. For a start, use `console.log` instead of `alert`. (You can observe the results opening the developer console)

Comment: The code looks like it's working correctly. What is the expected result? Why do you push objects into array instead of the positions, wouldn't just pushing the position value be enough (as the key you're pushing is already the index of the element in the array)?

Comment: Instead of alert(positions); try console.log(positions) in Chrome Developers Console and you will be able to see the objects. @Hermi

Comment: Thanks for the help and I am able to expand in the console per your suggestions, however I want to be able to retrieve the value of the properties - positions.comment1, positions.comment2, etc.  When I use console.log(positions.comment1), I get an undefined response.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `alert`, the array of object is collapsed into `[Object object]`, so you can instead do this to expand the content inside it:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(positions));
```

Or even better, you should print the result into the console window so you can inspect the content of your array even more comfortably:

```
console.log(positions);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to be able to access the value of each property - positions.comment1, positions.comment2, etc.  However, I'm receiving an undefined response in the console.

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined since `alert` gave you [Object object] hint. Where have you added `console.log`?